# Data is not transferring from Client to Server in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform

Main purpose of this code is, when we have data in database it should fetch and display on the browser. But i couldn't find it.

Problem is transferring data to the Server.

After running the meteor and enter some value from console of the browser,i am not able to see them back on the browser.But i am able to find them with in console by using the command "Tdos.find().fetch()",it is showing arrays that i have entered but if i am trying to find in mongodb console, we couldn't find it. Can Some one figure out my problem and where am i going wrong?

```
  <head>
     <title>simpletodos</title>
  </head>

 <body>

     {{> todoList}}
 </body>


  <template name="todoList">
  <h3>Todos</h3>
   <ul>
  {{#each tdos}}
      {{> todo}}
  {{/each}}
 </ul>
     <button class="add-todo">Add todo</button>

  </template>
  <template name="todo">
      <li>
       {{label}}
   </li>
</template>
```

Client/Main.js

```
  if(Meteor.isClient) {

    Template.todoList.helpers({
     todos: function() {
     return Tdos.find();
    }
  });

    if(Meteor.isServer) {

    }
  }
```

Server/main.js

```
  import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

  Tdos = new Mongo.Collection("tdos");

 Meteor.startup(() => {
   // code to run on server at startup
  });
```

Comment: Hi Sravan, your collection should be declare both on server and client side. If you define the collection in a collection.js file, be sure to make it available for client and server.(like lib folder)

Comment: I want to show my folder structure.                                                                                           .Meteor -> 3 Folders (Client, Collection, Server). Under Client (Main.html,Main.css,Main.js). Under Collection (Tdos.js(Collection Declaration)). Under Server (Main.js).

Comment: Now it is Working Perfectly fine thank you Yann for giving reply for my question.

Answer (score 0):

In your server, you define the collection like this:

```
Tdos = new Mongo.Collection("tdos");
```

Which means the collection in Mongo is todos, and you can list the contents with

```
db.todos.find()
```

You can insert a record in mongo using this:

```
db.todos.insert({label: "My first to do"})
```

In Meteor when you want to fetch or insert/update, you use Tdos, eg

```
Tdos.insert(...};
```

Your helper lets the data be available as an array within your code. I think you need to change that to be

```
todos: function() {
    return Tdos.find().fetch();
}
```

Comment: Thank You Mikkel, for your response.

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and found some results and I did one more change also. That is, I changed the location of Collection declaration. I created a new folder named as Collection under that I placed the declaration alone in a js file. Now I can see the entries in the browser. But I couldn't find the collection in the mongodb terminal. As my collection name is "tdos". I tried as db.tdos.find()   But it is showing an empty array only...   Now how can I find the collection in MongoDB terminal?

Comment: It's working fine Mikkel, Thank you for replying to my question.